# Migrating ArcGIS Pro project files to geodatabase without losing data

Tags: arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase

I have some projects going on with ArcGIS Pro but I saved my files in a random folder or different folders and then dragged and dropped. Now I'd like to put everything into the geodatabase for each project so that it's just cleaner and better to work with - especially because I have to update the Excel tables often.

How can I do while still not messing everything up in my project?

It is mostly shapefiles but also free standing csv tables that I linked to shapefiles and csv tables with coordinates that I used to build the layer.

Essentially, I need all the project files in one place (the geodatabase). Right now they're in several different folders, which means if I move one, it will no longer show up in ArcGIS Pro when I open it.
Additionally, I am using xls files with coordinates (point location) that I need to edit and update often and I'm looking for a way to do it dynamically without losing my visualization on ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here's a manual solution.  Open up your project and export each layer to your target geodatabase.  Make a backup of your project and your current layers, then move them to another location.  Reopen your project, and all the layers will have red exclamation points after them indicating they can't find their data.  You can click on each and redirect it to the matching geodatabase version, or you could use the repair data location option when right clicking.  With luck they will all repair with the first, but if not repeat each layer.  Then save.